# How do I duplicate items in Minecraft Bedrock creative mode?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do I duplicate items in Minecraft Bedrock edition? To clarify, I mean in creative mode, I don't want cheats in my survival worlds.

I've seen plenty of answers to similar questions, but they never seem to work in Bedrock. Is this just my mouse, or a limitation from Microsoft?

Answer (score 5):

The 'Pick Block' key does not work to duplicate items on Bedrock edition in creative mode at the time of this writing (v1.16.201 on Windows 10).

However, duplication can still be done by duplicating a *container*.

1. Place a shulker box and load it up with items that you want to duplicate. This is nice for heavily enchanted items because it's a pain to place all those enchantments all over again for each item.
   [image: Stash items in the shulker box]
2. Break the shulker box and pick it up. Hovering over it will show a brief description of what's in it.
   [image: Shulker description]
3. Now this same shulker box can be placed as many times as you'd like, it won't leave your inventory, effectively duplicating everything in it.
   [image: Place to duplicate]
4. **Note:** Attempting to use the 'Pick Block' bound key on these placed shulkers will only pick an empty shulker box. You'll need to pick one up and continue from step 2 to continue duplicating the items within them.
   [image: Placing picked shulker]
   [image: Picked shulker is empty]

Comment: or just use ctrl if on W10, going into survival is just more work (but necessary if not on windows 10)

Comment: @Penguin Ctrl? Can you elaborate on what you mean? Also, I don't think I mentioned survival. 

Comment: @Penguin Oh okay, I see what you mean. Just saw the other answer. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

> how do i duplicate items in minecraft bedrock edition

You can place the items you want to copy inside of a chest or other block that can hold items. Then, use the 'Pick Block' keybind while holding <kbd>Control</kbd> at the same time to get that chest as an item and place the copied chest down to extract the copied contents.

> Is this just my mouse

No, you can rebind the 'Pick Block' keybind to anything in the settings screen.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 Pick Block does exist on Bedrock Edition. I'm not entirely sure if it works in the inventory, but it does at least work for blocks.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 but this is 10x better than just saying "you cant" - this is what is wanted and almost *expected*, something that does work

Answer (score 1):

This only works in Creative Mode in Windows Bedrock (it doesn't work with consoles)!

- First go into Settings > Keyboard and Mouse > Keyboard Layout > Pick Block.
- Set the key-bind that you want, I'm using <kbd>p</kbd>:

  [image: Image showing what I just explained]
- Then place a chest and put all the stuff you want to duplicate in it:

  [image: Chest full of items]
- Then hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> (i.e. your key bind), and you should get a chest back with a `+Data` tag:

  [image: Image showing Data Tag]

Comment: @Joachim It shows that there are items inside the chest.. if it doesn't show that then it didn't duplicate the items and just picked a normal chest.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 0):

If you go into settings, go to controller, then at the bottom select the empty square next to “pick block” and press a button to bind. If you press this while hovering over a block, you will get that block. You can even get spawn eggs by clicking a mob. However, you do not keep the blocks data. So it can’t copy items in a chest, text on signs, or commands in a command block.